# Getting a Error : warning C4715: : not all control paths return a value but unsure why

Tags: c++

So I have a search that tells me if a value is in a list but its giving me this error and not sure why?

```
bool find(pNode* t, deque<unique_ptr<pNode>>& openList)
{

    for (auto p = openList.begin(); p != openList.end(); p++) 
    {
        if (t->x == (*p)->x && t->y == (*p)->y)
        {
            cout << "The coords searched for are in the open list" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `openList` is empty? The `for` loop wouldn't execute, and the function will immediately return. Now, try to answer this question: _what_ will it return in this case?

Comment: You only check the first element, but the output seems to suggest you wanted to search the whole queue...

Comment: What is the point of having a cycle, if the cycle never iterates?

Comment: If your function is supposed to return something then you need to make sure that last line before the last `}` has a return statement.

Comment: Also, you don't need to write `for` loops to search for an item in a container.  Use `std::find_if` or `std::find`.  If you had done that, then more than likely you never had encountered the warning (since your code would be structured differently).

Comment: Also, `pNode* t` should be a const reference (`const pNode& t`) in this situation

Comment: Think "empty container" the loop never executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not iterate, it only reports if the first node match's `t`. When `openList` is empty, the for loop is never entered. Notice that if the loop is not entered no `return` statement is encountered before the end of the function. You probably meant to place the return false statement outside of the loop, which solves all of these problems and gives you the expected behavior. Additionally `openList` should be const in this case.

```
bool find(pNode* t, const deque<unique_ptr<pNode>>& openList)
{

    for (auto p = openList.begin(); p != openList.end(); p++) 
    {
        if (t->x == (*p)->x && t->y == (*p)->y)
        {
            cout << "The coords searched for are in the open list" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Consider using [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead.

```
#include <algorithm>
bool find(pNode* t, deque<unique_ptr<pNode>>& openList)
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(openList.begin(), openList.end(), 
        [t](const unique_ptr<pNode> & p_Ptr){
            return p_Ptr->x == t->x && p_Ptr->y == t->y;
        });
    return iter != openList.end();
}
```

Or

```
bool find(pNode* t, const deque<unique_ptr<pNode>>& openList)
{
    for (auto && ptr : openList) {
        if (t->x == ptr->x && t->y == ptr->y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have improved things, I will consider the other 2 options provided also, but for now the first one was ok

Except I get a "Access violation reading location 0x00000004."  error at runtime at line 6 of this code ( if (t->x == (*p)->x && t->y == (*p)->y)  )

Answer (score 1):

You're making the classic newbie mistake when searching a list, putting the "false" result in the `else` clause inside the loop. You can't tell that something hasn't been found until you finish the loop, not after a single test failure.

```
bool find(pNode* t, deque<unique_ptr<pNode>>& openList)
{
    for (auto p = openList.begin(); p != openList.end(); p++) 
    {
        if (t->x == (*p)->x && t->y == (*p)->y)
        {
            cout << "The coords searched for are in the open list" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```